# Getting index of element in ArrayList On Click in android programming?

Tags: android, arraylist, indexing

I have an ArrayList of ImageButtons in my LinearLayout in android,
when it clicked my own "OnClick" event handler method run.

I want to get an index of an element(ImageButton) in ArrayList from its own OnClick event.

However, I cannot make a solution so far.

Otherwise I should create a custom ImageButton which has an index as integer,
which is more complicated.

Is there any good solution for it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could iterate through your collection until you find the member that matches...

Comment: You can create get the ID of the ImageButtons and the ID of the view who is being touched and then iterate through the elements of the ArrayList to see which match the touched view ID.

Comment: You should add ID for imageButtons.

Comment: You can create a separate listener object for each button so that you don't have to worry about which one was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this. It may help you.

```
//This is your arraylist of buttons
ArrayList<ImageButton> buttons ;

...

//This is your click listener
onClick(View view){

   ImageButton clickedButton = (ImageButton)view;
   int index = buttons.indexOfObject(clickedButton);
   if(index!=-1){
     //Your imagebutton clicked
   }
}
```